# Comparar dentro de un TRIGGER en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo unas tablas una que es de infracciones, y otra que es historial de infracciones que tiene los siguientes datos

TABLA INFRACCIONES

-idMulta (int)

-PLACAS (VARCHAR)

-DEUDA (FLOAT)

me dice que haga un trigger para comparar si ya existe unas placas en el registro, y si existen pues que le agrega mas deuda a sus placas, y si no, la agregue nada mas como nuevas placas violandoras de la ley, el chiste es que no se como comparar si es que existen en el registro, el registro digamos es

(idMulta,PLACAS,DEUDA) VALUES (1,A520,100) o sea que si panchito se pasa de listo, y lo agarra la policia siendo un criminal, verificaran si ya existe aumentando su deuda, y si no pues, le agregaran como nuevo violador de la ley metiéndolo en el registro,
me gustaría saber como comparar dentro del trigger para que inserte a panchito mas deuda o solamente lo agregue y ya, muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask], ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado, qué has intentado y qué problemas/errores tienes? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.